# How can I find out the number of times a string appears in a txt file?

Tags: python

I have been provided with a file path to a .txt (P) file and a string (S). I need to output how many times S appears in P.

Code I entered is:

```
import re
results = re.findall(S, P)
print(len(results))
```

Program Failed for Input: ../content/textfiles/parrot.txt parrot

Expected Output: 3

Your Program Output: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `"parrot.txt"` is the name of a text file in which the string `"parrot"` appears 3 times. You have correctly determined that `"parrot"` appears in the *file name* `"parrot.txt"` just once. You will need to open and read the text file if you want to count how many times `"parrot"` appears not in the name but in the file itself.

Comment: Thank you John. That is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Before the ```import re``` I added ```file1=open(P,'r') data=file1.read()```

Comment: That should solve it, although you should make sure to close the file (or use `with`) as well. Being Python, I suspect that the file is an excerpt of the famous [Dead Parrot sketch](http://www.montypython.50webs.com/scripts/Series_1/53.htm). The full transcript contains many more than 3. If this answer solves the problem adequately, you can consider marking it as accepted (via the check mark next to the question).